# Javascript - Get character between two characters using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this `"[Total MM] / [Total-MD] - [Total-MC]"`. I want to get only characters between `]` and `[` using regex on javascript. Example in this string above, return only `"/"` and `"-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I think the most straightforward is two regexes: one to match the content between `]` and `[` and another to remove the brackets and whitespace:

```
var str = "[Total MM] / [Total-MD] - [Total-MC]";
str
    .match(/\].*?\[/g)
    .map(m => m.replace(/\]\s*|\s*\[/g, ''));
```

Here's a [CodePen with a live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxyGVo).

Comment: thanks @Ethan Brown so much. it's for me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Hi Ethan, I see in your answer have syntax `=>`, it's look like in LinQ in C#.  It's same?

Comment: It is ES6 syntax...you can replace the `=>` with `function` syntax

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\]\s*([^[]+?)\s*\[
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iT9sF7/1)

```
var re = /\]\s*([^[]+?)\s*\[/g; 
var str = '[Total MM] / [Total-MD] - [Total-MC]';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks @Tim007, your answer look good, but you forgot remove two characters `"["` and `"]"`

Comment: @Võ Minh Phong it's in captured values, not matched values

Comment: How will this behave if the string does not start with a bracketed expression?

Answer (score 1):

Create a regexp which matches what IS inside the brackets, but doesn't capture it; then an alternative to capture everything else.

```
/\[.*?\]|([^[]*)/g
 ^^^^^^^               MATCH STUFF IN BRACKETS, DO NOT CAPTURE
          ^^^^^^       MATCH ANYTHING ELSE, DO CAPTURE
```

See https://regex101.com/r/oQ8pB2/1. See "Match Information" to the right.